# yii2 disable access by right part of routing rule

Tags: yii2

In `web.php` I have following code:

```
'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        // Disable index.php
        'showScriptName' => false,
        // Disable r= routes
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => array(
                'calc' => 'site/calc',
        ),
    ],
```

And I want to allow users to access to `example.com/calc` but not to `example.com/site/calc`. How I can do it properly with less effort? By other words now works both options - "`site/calc`" and "`calc`" and I want to disable "`site/calc`".

Comment: `urlManager` is in `components` part ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Btw, I got the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add enableStrictParsing to UrlManager configuration as follows

```
 'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    // Disable index.php
    'showScriptName' => false,
    // Disable r= routes
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'rules' => array(
            'calc' => 'site/calc',
    ),
],
```

In this case if there's no rule matching the request then it's considered as bad one.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to mark the answer as right one.;)